# How to determine if two IPs are on the same subnet using the IP's integer values (in C)?

Tags: c, binary, ip, decimal, subnet

"In software one usually stores IPv4 addresses in a single 32-bit variable -- so 126.127.0.1 is 01111110011111110000000000000001 binary (which also encodes 2122252289 decimal, except that nobody ever cares what the decimal value of a 32-bit IP address is), and it is converted to dotted-decimal only when it needs to be shown to human users." -taken from a similar question found here: [Determining if two IP adresses are on same subnet - is it leading or trailing 0s get dropped from IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148747/determining-if-two-ip-adresses-are-on-same-subnet-is-it-leading-or-trailing-0s)

What is above in quotes explains what I'm talking about. I've been told to obtain the integer value from two dotted-decimal IP address' and the integer value of a subnet mask as well. With these three integer values, I am to determine if the two IPs are in the same subnet, using the mask. I'm confused as to what to do with these three integer values to get my answer. Normally, I would stop at the binary value for each and then AND them together to get my answer, but it seems like I must do something with the integer values to get the answer and not simply AND the binary values. What might that be?

(By the way, this is to be done in C and I already have all of the code working to get to the integer values of each)

Thanks.

Comment: The accepted answer to the Q you link is telling you *exactly* how to do what you're asking. What part of it is confusing you, specifically? I'm not quite sure what you mean when you talk about "integer" and "binary" values ... those are the same thing.

Comment: For this assignment I'm doing, first comes the dotted-decimal IP, then we're told to obtain the binary value for the IP address, AND THEN using the binary value, determine the decimal value. I see how to get my answer from the other question, but they are using the binary value. I'm confused because I don't see the purpose in even bothering with the decimal value when the answer can be determined with the binary value which we're told to obtain BEFORE the decimal value. I'm wondering how to get my answer using only the decimal values and never bothering with binary values, if possible.

Comment: There are exactly 2 forms involved; the textual dotted-decimal representation, and those 4 octets (bytes) held in a 4-byte (32bit) `int` (The "binary" representation). You convert everything to `int`, then bitwise AND each IP against the bitmask to see if they're in the same subnet.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question you link really tells you everything you need to know:

Given three numbers, `IP1`, `IP2`, `mask`, you simply do

```
if(IP1 & mask == IP2 & mask) {
  printf("they are in the same subnet\n");
}
```