# How to compare whether two interfaces are configured within the same subnet

Tags: python, networking, ip-address, mask, subnet

Is there a easy way to determine multiple interfaces are configured in same subnet. I am planning as below but not sure whether it is the best solution

split ip address based on dot
split mask based on dot
& 4 parts and
join using dot.
Finally compare using dict or some other way.

Comment: Can you be more specific and tell us *exactly* what you mean by "within the same subnet"?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148747/determining-if-two-ip-adresses-are-on-same-subnet-is-it-leading-or-trailing-0s?rq=1

Comment: Yes Ashish, my approach is based on your link. But are there any python built in functions to do the same

Comment: `ipaddress` module in python 3

Comment: The real way to do it is to convert the text representation of an IP address to its native 32-bit integer, then do a bitwise `AND` with the mask to get the network. This is how IP was designed to be used. The dotted decimal notation of IPv4 is only to make it easier for humans to read, and you should never try to manipulate that. Instead, do it natively with 32-bit integers. IPv6 will work the same way with 128-bit integers.